# How to read bytes from user in python

Tags: python-2.x

May I know how can I read bytes from end user using command line.

I tried with

```
a = input("Enter your bytes data\n")
```

but that is reading strings.
I am using python 2 version.

Please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Could you provide an example on the Input that you want the users to enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, strings *are* sequences of bytes in the sense that a Python 2 string object is roughly equivalent to a Python 3 `bytes` object.

In Python 3 you would use `b'AB\xE2'` for the `bytes` object consisting of the 3 bytes `0x41 0x42 0xE2`. That also works with Python 2 (with or without the `b` -- which was backported to Python 2), though the result in Python 2 is a `str` object.

A user can enter such literals directly in Python 2:

```
a = input("Enter your bytes data\n")
```

Would look like this from the user's point of view:

```
Enter your bytes data
b'AB\xe2'
```

After this interaction, `a` would be the string of length consisting of those bytes (i.e `a = 'AB\xE2').

In the above it is important that the user actually enters the quote marks to get a valid literal. Needless to say, that might be a hassle and somewhat error-prone. Furthermore, using `input` at all is arguably suboptimal since it is in some sense depreciated. Python 3 dropped it in favor of `raw_input()` (which they somewhat confusingly renamed `input()`). It tends to be safer to just grab the user's input as a string and then explicitly do any needed conversions.

As an alternative, you could use `raw_input` to create a custom input function designed to take space-delimited hex numbers, each representing 1 byte (similar to the typical output of a hex-dump). Something like:

```
def get_bytes(prompt):
    hexes = raw_input(prompt).split()
    return ''.join(chr(int(h,16)) for h in hexes)
```

For example, if you run

```
a = get_bytes("enter binary in space-delimited hex: ")
```

User input would look like:

```
enter binary in space-delimited hex: 41 42 e2
```

after which `a` is the same byte-string as before.